# How to create a stacked bar chart with gaps between values of each variables in Python

Tags: python-3.x, graph

I have a problem with creating a stacked bar chart in Python.
I have data with 3 variables as below:

```
A=[3,5,7]

B=[4,5,7]

C=[2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

I would like to create a bar chart with gaps of values of each variable as below

bar chart with gaps between values of each variable :

[image]

Could anyone help me with this graph? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you want to draw a color table or something close to a Gantt diagram. I don't know really convenience ways to do this in Python.

One solution is to use `matplotlib.pyplot.grid` [(doc)](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.grid.html). This discussion provides one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971138/python-plotting-colored-grid-based-on-values).

Another solution is to study the `plotly` package. It provides really pretty outputs for table and gantt graphs [(doc)](https://plot.ly/python/table/).

Here, I will show you a similar output using `hbar` from **matplotlib**. The main idea is to rebuild a grid of cells. Each row represent a class (e.g. `A`, `B` or `C`). Each row is composed by the same number of cells. Each cell has the same width. The color of a cell is defined by the binary translation of your data.

To adjust the `x-axis` labels, they are just shifted manually.

```
# Import module
import seaborn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

##########################
#       Your input       #
##########################

A = [3, 5, 7]
B = [4, 5, 7]
C = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]


##########################
# Prepra the data        #
##########################
my_list = [A, B, C]
segments = 8
cell_width = 1000
nb_x_range = [i * cell_width for i in range(2, segments)]
classes = ["A", "B", "C"]
colors_def = {'A': {0: "w", 1: "b"},
              'B': {0: "w", 1: "g"},
              'C': {0: "w", 1: "y"},
              }

def create_data(my_list):
    data = np.zeros((segments + 1, len(classes)))
    for i, sub_list in enumerate(my_list):
        for elt in sub_list:
            data[elt, i] = 1
    return data

data = create_data(my_list)
print(data)
# [[0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1.]
#  [1. 0. 1.]
#  [0. 1. 1.]
#  [1. 1. 1.]
#  [0. 0. 1.]
#  [1. 1. 1.]
#  [0. 0. 0.]]

y_pos = np.arange(len(classes))
# left alignment of data starts at zero
left = np.zeros(len(my_list)) - cell_width/2


##########################
#       Create plot      #
##########################
# Set sea born for prettier graph
seaborn.set()
# create figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# Set X axis (shifted)
ax.set_xlim((min(nb_x_range)-cell_width/2, max(nb_x_range)+cell_width/2))

# For each cell
for d in data:
    # Define color for each row
    colors = [colors_def[classes[i]][bi] for i, bi in enumerate(d)]
    # e.g. colors = [colors_def["A"][d[0]], colors_def["B"][d[1]], colors_def["C"][d[2]]]

    # Draw cell
    ax.barh(y_pos, cell_width,
            height=1,           # Heights of horizontal bars
            color=colors,       # Colors
            left=left)          # Left padd from y-axis
    # Update margin
    left += cell_width

# Axis graduation
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_xticks(nb_x_range)
ax.set_yticklabels(classes)
ax.set_xlabel('Stacked bar')

plt.show()
```

The output looks like this:
[image]