# imshow uses a seemingly random background color

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am trying to use `imshow()`, with categorical data. But I cannot reliably control the colors used. This is my code (inspired in the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971138/python-plotting-colored-grid-based-on-values)

```
from random import choice
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # draw pretty stuff
from matplotlib import colors

def draw_trace2(mem_trace):
    print(f"Matrix: {mem_trace.block_size} rows, {mem_trace.len()} cols")
    # this prints: 'Matrix: 80 rows, 178 cols'

    dummy = True
    if dummy:
        # create dummy data
        access_matrix = [
            [choice([10,10,10,10,20,30]) for x in range(mem_trace.len())]
            for y in range(mem_trace.block_size)]
    else:
        # create real data
        access_matrix = [
            [10 for x in range(mem_trace.len())]
            for y in range(mem_trace.block_size)]
        for ac in mem_trace.access_list:
            for i in range(ac.size):
                access_matrix[ac.offset+i][ac.time] = 20 if ac.action=='R' else 30

    # paranoically check correct values
    for row in access_matrix:
        for cell in row:
            if cell not in [10,20,30]:
                raise ValueError("Wrong Value")

    # create discrete colormap. Credit to the previously cited SO answer
    cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['white', 'green', 'red'])
    bounds = [0,15,25,35]
    norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

    # draw and export image
    fig, axe1 = plt.subplots()
    axe1.imshow(access_matrix, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    fig.set_size_inches(100,44)
    fig.savefig('mem_trace_plot.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
    return
```

- `dummy=True`: I get dummy data with a red background.
- `dummy=False`: I get the real data, with what looks to be 50% gray background or sometimes red too

My intention is to have white background. Another oddity: If I reduce the size of the plot (for example, `fig.set_size_inches(10,4.4)`) the problem goes away.

Comment: It is not reproducible right now, what is `mem_trace`. Also add what your plot looks like and expected output (if you can)

Comment: Removed `mem_trace` as I don't know what it is, but `dummy=True` works as expected on my end (no red background).

Comment: Could it be related to this: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/25806/ ? The workaround seems to be to use `axe1.imshow(access_matrix, interpolation='none')`

Comment: I thought it fixed the problem, but it is still there.